# StackOverflowError when using Iterator to iterate through a list

Tags: java, iterator

I am trying to implement a toArray() method on a list. Initially I got an error saying I could only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.iterable when using the for each loop, so I did some research and tried using the Iterator. However, now it looks like it's stuck in something like a recursive loop (I think). Here is the section of my code I'm having trouble with:

```
public Object[] toArray(){
    Object[] arr = new Object[this.size()]
    int i = 0;
    for(E e: this){
        arr[i] = e;
        i++;
    }
    return arr;
}

@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return this.iterator();
}
```

I've narrowed it down to how I've defined my `public Iterator<E> iterator()` method since the program works ok if I use other values instead of `this` in the foreach loop. The error I'm getting is 
`Exception in thread "main"java.lang.StackOverflowError 
at arrayIndexList.ArrayIndexList.iterator(ArrayIndexList.java:158)` repeated exactly as it is over and over again, but not in an infinite loop since it terminates. When I click `ArrayIndexList.java:158` it takes me to the `return this.iterator()` in my code. What am I missing here?

Comment: `public Iterator<E> iterator() { return this.iterator(); }`??? Seriously. This is nothing but undesired recursion. Don't do this.

Comment: I thought "this" would refer to whatever object is being looked at in the for each loop in toArray()

Comment: No. This refers to `this`, the current object itself. Delete that code and instead return the iterator of your class's collection or array.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to pass the `Class<E>` to your constructor and save it so you can construct your array type properly in `toArray()` - and return an `E[]`. Then you can wrap that with a `List` and return the `iterator()` of that. Like,

```
private Class<E> cls; // <-- make sure you assign this in your constructor

public E[] toArray() {
    E[] arr = Array.newInstance(cls, this.size()); // <-- here is how you get an E[]
    int i = 0;
    for (E e : this) {
        arr[i] = e;
        i++;
    }
    return arr;
}

@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return Arrays.asList(this.toArray()).iterator();
}
```